# cannot connect cin with back_insert_iterator

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to connect back_inserter_iterator and cin, I understand that I could use copy with cin and back_inserter, but wanted to know why cannot I perform the below

```
list<string> name;
back_insert_iterator<list<string>> ins_it(name);

while (cin >> ins_it);
```

The following is the error message I am getting:

> error: cannot bind ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}’
>   lvalue to ‘std::basic_istream&&’

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> wanted to know why cannot I perform the below...

The reason is the design of [`std::back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator).

That type only performs a back insertion when using [`operator =`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator/operator=).  Which is why `std::copy` *does* work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Drew,  I got confused with the error message g++ threw. 
"error: cannot bind ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_istream<char>&&’ "

Answer (score 3):

Canonical ways to do it (if there is such a thing):

```
list<string> name{
    istream_iterator<string>{cin}, 
    istream_iterator<string>{}};
```

or:

```
list<string> name;
copy(istream_iterator<string>{cin}, istream_iterator<string>{},
    back_inserter(name));
```

Comment: Does this really answer the question? *"I understand that I could use copy with cin and back_inserter, but wanted to know why cannot I perform the below"*

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Yes, it does. It shows the crucial step the OP left out: using an `istream_iterator`. Using `copy` (or not) is mostly irrelevant; using an `istream_iterator` is what makes the difference here.

Comment: And of course, unless he's using C++11, this won't work.  He'll have to use the classical initializers for `istream_iterator`, and take steps to avoid the most embarassing parse.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: So, what do you think he meant when he said the above quote? How do you think he managed to "use copy with cin and back_inserter" if he was missing the the crucial step of using an `istream_iterator`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Given the OP's vagueness, it's difficult to be sure what he managed to do, but this does show how to do the job, including an example that doesn't use `copy`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I have edited my response to address the question fully (along with your point).

Comment: @utnapistim: I think you'll find, if you test that, that it does not work.  Output iterators have strange behavior, necessitated by their nature.  See Drew's answer.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Sorry for the confusion, when I mentioned copy along with cin and back_inserter, I meant using copy with istream_iterator(cin), istream_iterator() and back_inserter(name) (or back_insert_iterator).  
My doubt was _why "\*ins_it = "one";" works and why "cin >> \*ins_it;" does not work_. I now understand that back_insert_iterator does not support <<, but supports =, but got confused with the error message that __g++__ threw.  
__error: cannot bind ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_istream<char>&&’__

Answer (score 0):

The operator>>() is not an *insert* operator, it is an *extract* operator.
A back inserter object expects insertion, not an extraction.
Summarizing, there is just no operator>>(istream, inserter).